# Hive outer join: how to change the default NULL value

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

For `hive` outer join, if a joining key does not exist in one table,`hive` will put `NULL`. Is that possible to use another value for this? For example:

Table1:

```
user_id, name, age
1        Bob   23
2        Jim   43
```

Table2:

```
user_id,   txn_amt,      date
 1          20.00      2013-12-10
 1          10.00      2014-07-01
```

If I do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `user_id`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE user_txn
SELECT 
     Table1.user_id,
     Table1.name,
     Table2.txn_amt,
     Table2.date
FROM
    Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table1
ON
Table1.user_id = Table2.user_id;
```

I want the output be like this:

```
user_id,    name,   tnx_amt,   date
1           Bob     20.00      2013-12-10
1           Bob     10.00      2014-07-01
2           Jim     0.00       2099-12-31
```

Note the `txn_amt` and `date` columns for Jim. Is there any way in `hive` to define default values like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) for this, instead of solely `Table2.txn_amt`

```
COALESCE(Table2.txn_amt, 0.0)
```

What this does is returns the first value that is not null. So, if `txn_amt` is null, it'll go to the second value in the list. `0.0` is never null, so it'll pick that. If `txn_amt` has a value in it, it'll return that value.

Comment: There's also the nvl function which returns a specified default value if the value is NULL.